# -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a little bit problem with `-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'` How can I show `(null)` If I don't have data.

Here's code

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if ([[bookList objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]quiz_url]==[[bookList objectAtIndex:6]quiz_url]) {// This one is problem, I have  `objectAtIndex:` only 0 - 5 .

//             quiz_all = [[bookList objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]quiz_url];
        _getQuiz6 = [[bookList objectAtIndex:6]quiz_url];
         NSLog(@" test quiz6 = %@",_getQuiz6); //It's possible? Can I print `(null)` if no data.
    }
...
```

and

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [bookList count];
}
```

I don't have data `[[bookList objectAtIndex:6]quiz_url]` on webservice.

Comment: the simple way would be to say `if(_getQuiz6 == nil)NSLog(@"null");`

Comment: but if you want a more complex answer then you can look at the answer i provided below

Comment: It sounds to me like your problem is that `bookList` doesn't contain 7 entries.  You need to test `if (boolList.count >= 7) { _getQuiz6 = [[booklist[6] quiz_url]; } else { _getQuiz6 = nil; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's plenty of ways you could go around this. One way to deal with it, is using "placeholder" objects to pad the content, for example, `NSNull`. Or you could modify your `Book` object and add a property like `isLoaded`.

Whatever method you choose, then (sticking with the `NSNull`);

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Whatever code you have

    Book *book = [bookList objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    // NSNull is a singleton, you can safely do pointer comparison
    if (book == [NSNull null])
    {
        // Show loading or something in the cell
        cell.loadingOrSomething = YES;

        // Return the cell here
        return cell;
    }

    // book wasn't NSNull, then proceed with the rest of stuff
    NSURL *url = [book quiz_url];

    cell.loadingOrSomething = NO;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,It's very nice.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a category if you want. Somewhere in a header include this:

```
@interface NSArray (custom)
-(id)quizURLAtIndex:(int)index;
@end
```

and in a .m file you add this:

```
@implementation NSArray (custom)

-(id)quizURLAtIndex:(int)index{
    if(index >= self.count) return nil;
    else return [[self objectAtIndex:index] quiz_url];
}

@end
```

And from now on, whenever you want, you can call `[bookList quizURLAtIndex:indexPath.item]` instead of `[[bookList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] quiz_url]`